# Degenerate moduli spaces in Floer homology

Tags: sg.symplectic-geometry, floer-homology

Let $(W,\omega)$ be a closed symplectially aspherical symplectic
manifold, and fix a Hamiltonian $H\in C^{\infty}(W\times S^{1};\mathbb{R})$
and a compatible almost complex structure $J$ on $W$. Given two
1-periodic orbits $x$ and $y$ of $H$, let $\mathcal{M}(x,y;H,J)$
denote the set of maps $w\in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}\times S^{1};W)$
that satisfy

$\mathcal{F}_{H,J}(w):=\partial_{s}w+J(w)\partial_{t}w+\nabla H_{t}(w)=0$

where $\nabla H_{t}$ is the gradient of $H$ with respect to the
metric $\omega(\cdot,J\cdot)$. Let $\mathcal{M}(H,J)$ denote the
union of the spaces $\mathcal{M}(x,y;H,J)$ as $x$ and $y$ run through
the 1-periodic orbits of $H$. Well known elliptic regularity results
tellus that the space $\mathcal{M}(H,J)$ is bounded in the $C_{loc}^{\infty}$
topology on $C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}\times S^{1};W)$.

It is well known that if:

(1) all 1-periodic orbits of $H$ are non-degenerate, and

(2) the pair $(H,J)$ is regular (meaning that $d\mathcal{F}_{H,J}(w)$
is surjective for all $w\in\mathcal{M}(H,J)$),

then for any 1-periodic orbits $x,y$ the space $\mathcal{M}(x,y;H,J)$
is a finite dimensional manifold.

The spaces $\mathcal{M}(x,y;H,J)$
carry a free $\mathbb{R}$-action via translation, and hence they
obviously can never be compact. Instead one can look at the quotient
spaces $\mathcal{M}(x,y;H,J)/\mathbb{R}$ obtained by dividing out
by this action. In general the spaces $\mathcal{M}(x,y;H,J)/\mathbb{R}$
are still not compact, but it is possible to obtain a very precise
description of the closure $\overline{\mathcal{M}(x,y;H,J)/\mathbb{R}}$
(in the topology induced from the $C_{loc}^{\infty}$ topology on
$C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}\times S^{1};W)$).

For instance, if $dim(\mathcal{M}(x,y;H,J))=1$
then $\overline{\mathcal{M}(x,y;H,J)/\mathbb{R}}=\mathcal{M}(x,y;H,J)/\mathbb{R}$
(and hence $\mathcal{M}(x,y;H,J)/\mathbb{R}$ is compact), and if
$dim(\mathcal{M}(x,y;H,J))=2$ then the boundary $\partial(\overline{\mathcal{M}(x,y;H,J)/\mathbb{R})}$
is precisely equal to the union $\cup_{z}\overline{\mathcal{M}(x,z;H,J)/\mathbb{R}}\times\overline{\mathcal{M}(z,y;H,J)/\mathbb{R}}$
where $z$ runs over all the 1-periodic orbits such that $dim(\mathcal{M}(x,z;H,J))=1$.
This latter fact is precisely why the boundary operator in Floer homology
really is a boundary operator.

Suppose now that we are given two pairs $(H^{a},J^{a})$ and $(H^{b},J^{b})$
of Hamiltonians that satisfy (1) and (2) above, and suppose we are
given a family $(H_{s},J_{s})$ ($s\in\mathbb{R}$) such that $(H_{s},J_{s})\equiv(H^{a},J^{a})$
for $s$ near $-\infty$ and $(H_{s},J_{s})\equiv(H^{b},J^{b})$ for
$s$ near $+\infty$. Then if $x$ is a periodic orbit of $H^{a}$
and $y$ is a periodic orbit of $H^{b}$, we can again look at the
spaces $\mathcal{M}(x,y;H_{s},J_{s})$, which are defined in the same
way, only now $H$ and $J$ depend on $s$. If $(H_{s},J_{s})$ satisfies
the property:

(3) The operator $d\mathcal{F}_{H_{s},J_{s}}(w)$ is surjective for all $w\in\mathcal{M}(H_{s},J_{s})$,

then the spaces $\mathcal{M}(x,y;H_{s},J_{s})$ are again finite dimensional
manifolds, and as before we have a good description of the closures
$\overline{\mathcal{M}(x,y;H_{s},J_{s})}$. This fact is used to show
that $(H_{s},J_{s})$ induces a chain map $FH_{*}(H^{a})\rightarrow FH_{*}(H^{b})$
on the Floer homology groups.

**Anyway, my question is this:**

Suppose we drop assumptions
(1), (2) and (3) above. **How bad can the spaces $\mathcal{M}(x,y;H_{s},J_{s})$
be?** In order to make this a proper question, I will focus on a special
case (although I am also interested in answers that address the general
case). Consider the special case where $H^{a}=H^{b}=H$ and $x=y$.
Thus $x$ is a (possibly degenerate) orbit of $H$, and $(H_{s},J_{s})$
is any family (not necessarily regular) such that $(H_{s},J_{s})\equiv(H,J)$
for $\left|s\right|$ large. Do we have any information about what
the closure of $\mathcal{M}(x,x,H_{s},J_{s})$ is like? For instance,
is it possible that there exists $(w_{n})_{n=1,2,3,\dots}$ in $\mathcal{M}(x,x;H_{s},J_{s})$
and $(s_{n})_{n=1,2,3,\dots}$ a bounded sequence of real number such
that $w_{n}(s_{n})\rightarrow z$ for a different 1-periodic orbit
$z\ne x$ of $H$?

Comment: Perhaps the most basic question in this context is whether $L^2$ solutions to Floer's equation converge to Hamiltonian orbits. I don't know of any reference for this, though perhaps it's in the minimal surfaces literature. The analogous property of instantons is proved by Morgan, Mrowka and Ruberman in "The $L^2$-moduli space and a vanishing theorem for Donaldson polynomial invariants", Monographs in Geometry and Topology, II. International Press, Cambridge, MA, 1994; MR1287851.